# Odd autorelease in XCode4.2.1 boilerplate code

Tags: ios, xcode, boilerplate

I was just reading through the boilerplate code for a universal app and I saw this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    ...
    [_navigationController release];
    ...
}
```

and yet also:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...
        self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure I understand the whole underscore thing, but I gather that it's to protect you from accessing the ivar directly, and instead accessing it through the property (why? I have no idea... but I accept that this is what its for).

However, what I don't get is that if `self.navigationController` is `autorelease`d then surely this will cause issues when `_navigationController` is released at the end?

Even more confusing is the fact that there is no `retain` bit in the `@property` for `navigationController`.

So as far as I can tell `_navigationController` accessed through the property `navigationController` is `autorelease`d and then directly accessed and release in dealloc (where it could already be autoreleased surely?).

lol, I hope someone can explain what's going on here! I'm sure the boilerplate code probably isn't wrong!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing from the question are two important statements: `@property` and `@synthesize`.

My best guess is that these are:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UINavigationController * navigationController;
```

and

```
@synthesize navigationController = _navigationController;
```

Since the @property specifies retain when the setter is called, "self.navigationController =", any existing value is released and the new value is retained. Thus an autorelease of the new value is counter acted by the retain in the setter.

The `@synthesize` statement says to use `_navigationController` as the ivar for the property `navigationController`.

This is not ARC code.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. So setting a property which has `retain` on it without using `autorelease` creates a retain count of 2? I'm not using ARC code, our contract with clients preserves backwards compatibility to iOS 4.2. I assume that ARC isn't available on 4.2 (or is it a compiler function)?

Comment: Having looked this up on writing this comment it would appear that ARC is a compile time function and not run time, does this mean that it will work with 4.2? If so does this question and the explanation you gave become useless? Or is the theory still important?

Comment: @ThomasClayson: Yes. ARC is available on iOS 4.x and up. There is one piece that is only available on iOS 5+ and that is automatic zeroing of weak references but that presents no reason not to use ARC. ARC (not including weak reference) is compile-time, the LLDB compiler just inserts the required rattan, release and autorelease behind-the-scenes (essentially). ARC can be configured on a file-by-file basis is necessary. Read up on ARC, it really is the future.

Comment: @ThomasClayson: ARC is a compiler function, ARC-code runs well on all iOS 4.x releases.

Comment: The @synthesize portion is still very relevant, the retain portion is not. Under ARC retain/release/autorelease produce compiler errors in files under ARC.

Comment: @Andrey: Z ARC is specified to run under iOS 4.0 and above only.

Comment: Thanks for all the clarification guys! :)

Answer (score 2):

you haven't posted the `@property`.
But I guess it's something like that:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

in non-ARC environments strong is a synonym for retain.
Apple stopped using retain in their properties with the introduction of ARC, even for non-ARC project templates.

So the navigationController is retained when assigned trough its setter and the autorelease is there to counteract the alloc.
But I'm pretty sure you understand those basic memory management rules already.

Comment: Oh right, so, am I right in saying that this property then does something like this: 1. You set `self.window = [... autorelease]` 2. This sets `_window` with a retain (from the `strong`) 3. self.window is autoreleased at a later date but `_window` still has a retain count of 1. 4. You release `_window` but not `self.window`.